# How to print back the correct delimiter when using a regex expression as delimiter?

Tags: text-processing, awk, arithmetic

I have lines that look like this

```
123-456-789 12.34.56 example
```

I want to select the 12, add 2 to it, then print the whole line as is. So the result should be :

```
123-456-789 14.34.56 example
```

I have this awk expression :

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ .]"}{$2=$2+2}{print}'
```

But it gives me

```
123-456-789 14 34 56 example
```

The dots are gone and replaced by spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to "*restore*" a complex/compound field separator will likely break some values and the consistency of the whole record.
Instead, use the following approach:

```
awk '{ n = substr($2, 1, index($2, ".")); sub(/[^.]+\./, n + 2 ".", $2) }1' file
```

The output:

```
123-456-789 14.34.56 example
```

---

The above command will use whitespace(s) as default field separator and perform all the needed processing on the 2nd field `$2` only.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ split($2,a,"\."); a[1]+=2; $2=sprintf("%d.%d.%d", a[1],a[2],a[3]) } 1' file
```

Alternatively,

```
awk '{ split($2,a,"\."); $2=sprintf("%d.%d.%d", a[1] + 2,a[2],a[3]) } 1' file
```

This reads the line as a set of whitespace-separated fields. It splits the second field on dots and adds 2 to the first part of the result. It then re-forms the second field as three dot-delimited integers before printing the resulting record (the printing is done by the `1` at the end which is a shortcut way of saying `{ print }`).

This assumes that we know that the second record is indeed three dot-delimited integers.

I would do it this way as it's quite explicit in what happens, and therefore easy to understand and to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` function in your `awk` script that allows capturing the field separator:

```
 awk '{split($0,a,"[- .]",sep); a[4]+=2; for(i in a) printf "%s%s",a[i], sep[i]; printf "\n"}' file
```

Alternatively, you can make use of `RS` and `RT` variables

```
 awk -v RS='[- .]' 'NR==4{$1+=2} {printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' file <<< '123-456-789 12.34.56 example'
```

Note that last one would only work for a single line.

Answer (score 0):

With gawk for gensub

```
gawk '{sub(/[^.]*/,gensub(/([^.]*).*/,"\\1",1,$2)+2,$2)}1' infile
```